# undefined is not a function epoch js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to run the basic example for a line chart from epoch (which is built on top of d3 ) http://fastly.github.io/epoch/basic/

Below is the code provided in the website:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="epoch.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/epoch.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="lineChart" style="width: 800px; height: 200px"></div>
    <script>

        var lineChartData = [
          // First series
          {
            label: "Series 1",
            values: [ {time: 1370044800, y: 100}, {time: 1370044801, y: 1000}]
          },

          // The second series
          {
            label: "Series 2",
            values: [ {time: 1370044800, y: 78}, {time: 1370044801, y: 98}]
          },
        ];

      $('#lineChart').epoch({
        type: 'time.bar',
        data: lineChartData
      });   
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function index.html:(line that has epoch keyword in it) (anonymous function)

Any ideas what is missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to switch your script includes around a little, putting jquery first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="epoch.min.js"></script>
```